# rest api POST request json key mismatch

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, http-post

I am writing a plain post request using spring boot web module, and the fields in my POST request are name, Description and title.

My question is when i use postman or any client to make a POST request to add a new entity, the json keys, name, Description and title are case sensitive, but how can i make the keys case-insensitive. in other words, even when user makes a post request using **d**escription instead of **D**escription my application should accept the value and rather not take null since it was not exact match.

Any thoughts are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write function to check your keys are present with case sensitive values or not. In get method you can call method to pick the key.

```
public String getIgnoreCase(JSONObject obj, String key) {

    Iterator<String> itr = obj.keySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String key1 = itr.next();
        if (key1.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
            return obj.get(key1);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since I use @RequestBody annotation for the POST request as follows where exactly can i use that function , for instance my post request may look like `@PostMapping("/add")   public ResponseEntity<Void> addNewItem(@RequestBody Item item) {  @autowired JpaRepository repository repository.save(item) return ResponseEntity<void>  }`       but i dont know where exactly i can write a validation function to check case insensitivity

Comment: public ResponseEntity<?> addNewItem(@RequestBody String itemData){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(itemData);
        String name = obj.optString(getIgnoreCase(obj,"name"));
  String description = obj.optString(getIgnoreCase(obj,"description"));
  String title = obj.optString(getIgnoreCase(obj,"title"));

Answer (score 0):

If u want to keep @RequestBody Item item. then here is solution:

in application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.accept_case_insensitive_properties=true
```

if you use application.yml then:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      accept_case_insensitive_properties: true
```